# How to only compile changed source code when compile ubuntu kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling

When I do some change to source code of ubuntu kernel, I have to fakeroot debian/rules clean and then compile the ubuntu kernel from scratch. But compiling the whole kernel spends a lot of time. Is there a way that I can only compile changed source code to save time?
Thanks

Comment: Kernel module (like a device driver): Yes. Main kernel: No, gotta compile the whoooole thing. Compile time is when you invent a clever new sandwich or wander over to the foosball table.

Comment: I never did figure out how to do an incremental compile for Ubuntu kernels the Ubuntu way. For the mainline, upstream, kernel incremental compile is trivial. Depending on the change the compile time can be over 5 times faster than a clean compile.